# Best way to check for a new tweet

Tags: ruby, twitter

Heres a piece of code from my irc bot. What it does is that it checks for new tweets at an specific account, then replies it in the channel.
Now, is there an better way to check for new tweets? that for i in 1..999999999 feels a bit unoptimal, and ddos'y.

```
tweetzsr = {}
xzsr = {}
zsr = {}

on :message, ".start zsr" do |m|
  if zsr[m.channel] == true
    m.reply "already doing it.."
  else
    m.reply "ok."
    zsr[m.channel] = true
    for i in 1..99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999
      sleep 60
      puts "#{xzsr[m.channel]} = x, tweetzsr = #{tweetzsr[m.channel]}"
      tweetzsr[m.channel] = Twitter.user_timeline("twiitterracount").first.text
      if xzsr[m.channel] == tweetzsr[m.channel]
        nil
      else
        m.reply "#{tweetzsr[m.channel]} - via twitter feed"
        xzsr[m.channel] = tweetzsr[m.channel]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that your infinite loop?

Change it to this to improve sanity

```
loop do
  sleep 60
  newtweet[m.channel] = Twitter.user_timeline("twitteracount").first.text
  next if oldtweet[m.channel] == newtweet[m.channel]
  m.reply "#{newtweet[m.channel]} - via twitter"
  oldtweet[m.channel] = newtweet[m.channel]
end
```

You're missing the two `end` keywords.

Comment: Idiomatic ruby should use rather `loop do` then `while true`.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, for an infinite loop use the `loop` method.

Best for this kind of thing is to use [Twitter's streaming api](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis/streams/user). This api will send a single request to Twitter, which will then push any new data to your client. For that there is a gem called [TweetStream](https://github.com/intridea/tweetstream).

Example usage:

```
TweetStream::Client.new.userstream do |status|
  m.reply "#{status.text} - via twitter"
end
```

Comment: I updated the code in my first link, which is all the code for my "twitter part", will tweetstream work with it?

Comment: Your code is a little messy, so I'm not completely sure what you are trying to do. In the above example the block will be called once for every new tweet (if you check out the docs, there is info about handling deletions and errors). I assume that is what you are trying to do in the code you show.